# purrr:::map_df() gives bind rows error

Tags: r, purrr

I want to sample a population twice and store the results in dataframe columns. If I run this code in R:

```
population <- rnorm(10000, 3, 3)
map_df(1:2, ~ sample(population, 10), .id = c("a", "b"))
```

It gives this error:

```
Error: .id is not a string
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you use `map_df`, your function should return a data.frame, you are just returning a vector. Try `map_df(1:2, ~ data.frame(x=sample(population, 10)))`

Comment: Also `.id=` just takes a single character value which names the new column that will identify the source. The value of the column will always be the numeric index where the data came from. You cannot change that during the map.

Comment: `as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, purrr::rerun(2, sample(population, 10))))
`

Comment: `map_df(data.frame(as.list(1:2)), ~ sample(population, 10))`

Comment: `map_df(1:2, ~ data.frame(x=sample(population, 10))` doesn't work as all 20 data points are in the same row. I need 2 rows each of length 10

Comment: `rerun(2, sample(population, 10)) %>% as_tibble(validate=F)`

Comment: There must be a better solution...

Comment: ugh: `map_df(1:2, ~ as.data.frame(t(data_frame(x = sample(population, 10)))), .id = "set")`

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a better solution @RyanMorton. I understood that OP wanted 2 columns and not 2 rows, could you please disambiguate @luciano?

Comment: Well, fair enough: `lmap(1:2, ~ data_frame(x = sample(population, 10))) %>%
  bind_cols()`